Prove via contraposition that if $(a_n)$ is decreasing and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n<\infty$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}na_n=0$
"Normal way"
Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a monotonically decreasing sequence of non-negative real numbers.
Furthermore, let $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ be convergent.
To show is $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\cdot a_n=0$
Cauchy's convergence test gives us $$\forall \varepsilon>0 \quad \exists N\in\mathbb{N} \quad \forall m > n \ge N \colon \quad \sum_{k=n+1}^m a_k < \varepsilon$$
Since $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is monotonically decreasing, we get $$(m-n)a_m\leq\sum_{k=n+1}^m a_k < \varepsilon$$
Now, let $m\geq 2N$ and $n:=\left\lfloor\frac{m}{2}\right\rfloor$, which satisfies $m > n \ge N$, so we get
$$\frac{m}{2}a_m\leq(m-n)a_m< \varepsilon$$
So, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{2}\cdot a_n=0$ and thus $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\cdot a_n=0$$
Contraposition
This wasn't a big deal, however I'm wondering, whether the statement can also be proven directly via its contraposition, so:
Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a monotonically decreasing sequence of non-negative real numbers.
Furthermore, let $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\cdot a_n\neq0$
To show is that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is not convergent.
By definition, we have $$\exists \varepsilon>0 \; \forall N\in\mathbb{N} \; \exists n \ge N\colon \; n\cdot a_n\geq\varepsilon$$
However, this only gives us $a_n\geq\frac{\varepsilon}{n}$, and then due to $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ being monotonically decreasing, we get $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\geq\varepsilon$, and that doesn't seem to be of much use.
Question
Do you see how the proof via contraposition could be done?

The negation of $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\cdot a_n=0$ ... either $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\cdot a_n$ exists and is nonzero, or $n\cdot a_n$ does not converge.

@GEdgar isn't that $\exists \varepsilon>0 ; \forall N\in\mathbb{N} ; \exists n \ge N\colon ; n\cdot a_n\geq\varepsilon$ ?

@Olivier04 Yes, I believe it is. In this setting, since the $(a_n)$ are decreasing and non-negative, convergence of $(na_n)$ is equivalent to $\limsup_n na_n = 0$, and what you wrote gives the negation of that.

Suppose there exists $\varepsilon>0$ and $\sigma:\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow\mathbb{N}$ strictly increasing such that $\sigma(n)a_{\sigma(n)}\geqslant\varepsilon$ for all $n$. Since $(a_n)$ is decreasing, we have $a_k\geqslant\frac{\varepsilon}{\sigma(n)}$ whenever $\sigma(n-1)+1\leqslant k\leqslant\sigma(n)$ so
$$ \sum_{k=\sigma(n-1)+1}^{\sigma(n)}a_k\geqslant\varepsilon\frac{\sigma(n)-\sigma(n-1)}{\sigma(n)}=\varepsilon\left(1-\frac{\sigma(n-1)}{\sigma(n)}\right). $$
We can suppose without loss of generality that $\sigma(n)\geqslant 2\sigma(n-1)$, which means that
$$ \sum_{k=\sigma(n-1)+1}^{\sigma(n)}a_k\geqslant\frac{\varepsilon}{2} $$
thus $\sum a_n$ can't be finite.

Since $(a_n)$ is decreasing, you have $a_k\geqslant a_{\sigma(n)}$ when $k\leqslant\sigma(n)$. For the second question, suppose you have $\sigma$ as in my answer, then you can define $\sigma'$ such that $\sigma'(0)=0$ and $$ \sigma'(n+1)=\min{ k>n,\sigma(k)\geqslant 2\sigma'(n) } $$ then, up to replacing $\sigma$ by $\sigma'$, you can suppose that $\sigma(n)\geqslant 2\sigma(n-1)$.

We have $a_k\geqslant\frac{\varepsilon}{\sigma(n)}$ when $k\leqslant\sigma(n)$, this works in particular if $\sigma(n-1)+1\leqslant k\leqslant\sigma(n)$. I added that because I sum over $k\in[![\sigma(n-1)+1,\sigma(n)]!]$.

I deleted my comments asking questions, because those are not needed anymore. After you have deleted your answers to those already deleted questions, I will delete this comment.

@Olivier04 I think it's better to let them, it may help someone who reads my answer and has the same questions you asked.

This answer is based on https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4899007/1311533
I am just rephrasing in my own words.
It is $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\cdot a_n\neq0$, which means $$\exists \varepsilon>0 \; \forall N\in\mathbb{N} \; \exists n \ge N\colon \; n\cdot a_n\geq\varepsilon$$
For every $N\in\mathbb{N}$, we are guaranteed to have an $M\in\mathbb{N}$ with $M\geq 2N$ such that $$M\cdot a_{M}\geq\varepsilon \Longleftrightarrow a_{M}\geq\frac{\varepsilon}{M}$$
Since $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is monotonically decreasing, we have $$\sum_{k=N+1}^{M} a_k \geq (M-N)\frac{\varepsilon}{M}\geq \frac{1}{2}\varepsilon$$
Thus, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is not convergent.
